# "KeyError" in pandas dataframe during Tokenization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

CODE:

```
ps = PorterStemmer()
tokens = []
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    tweet = str(df['clean_tweet'][i])
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    tweet = tweet.split()
    tweet = [ps.stem(word) for word in tweet if word not in stopWords]
    tweet = ' '.join(tweet)
    tokens.append(tweet)
    print(tokens[i])
df['clean_tweet'] = tokens
df.head()
```

THROWING KeyError for some reason.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3079             try:
-> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._get_loc_duplicates()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._maybe_get_bool_indexer()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine._unpack_bool_indexer()

KeyError: 31962

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-7794ad45df60> in <module>
      2 tokens = []
      3 for i in range(0,len(df)):
----> 4     tweet = str(df['clean_tweet'][i])
      5     tweet = tweet.lower()
      6     tweet = tweet.split()

~\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    851 
    852         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 853             return self._get_value(key)
    854 
    855         if is_hashable(key):

~\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
    959 
    960         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
--> 961         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    962         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
    963 

~\anaconda3\envs\machine_learning\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3083 
   3084         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 31962
```

I have no idea as to why this error is happening. The dataframe is of shape 56745 rows × 4 columns and apparently the code is able to convert the `tweet` to a tokenized tweet so I think the KeyError might be occurring when I am overriding the dataframe column with the list of tokens.

Comment: does the error rise from the for loop or after?

Comment: I think its after the loop since it's printing the tokens fine.

Comment: try to print the i before in the beginning of the loop to see which number/row you got. I also don't think this is the best practice to get the clean_tweet.

Comment: have you tried `for tweet in df['clean_tweet']:` for the loop instead?

Answer (score 0):

`KeyError: 31962` raises might be index of your dataframe is not continuous, and `31962` is missing. You can try `apply()` on Series

```py
def clean_tweet(tweet):
    tweet = tweet.lower()
    tweet = tweet.split()
    tweet = [ps.stem(word) for word in tweet if word not in stopWords]
    return ' '.join(tweet)

df['clean_tweet'] = df['clean_tweet'].apply(clean_tweet)
```